# static_cast() works but static_pointer_cast() does not?

Tags: c++, casting, smart-pointers, static-cast

When I write a class like this `static_cast()` calls the custom conversion operator. But `static_pointer_cast()` does not compile. Why is that, and what do I need to do to make it work?

```
class A{
   //class implementation
   operator int(){
      return 42;
   }
}

A a();
int i = static_cast<int>(a); //works i = 42

std::shared_ptr<A> pa = std::make_shared<A>();
std::shared_ptr<int> pi = static_pointer_cast<int>(pa); //does not compile
```

Edit: Ultimately I need to convert smart_ptr of templated class, where the templated argument is a derived class, e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo; 

class Base; 

class Derived: public Base{}

shared_ptr<Foo<Derived>> fb = make_shared<Foo<Derived>>();

shared_ptr<Foo<Base>> x = static_pointer_cast<Foo<Base>>(fb);
```

Comment: Does your compiler support the C++20 standard? This requires C++20.

Comment: You are trying to convert a `A*` to an `int*`, which will never work in a static cast.  You can cast an `A` to an `int` because you've defined an operator for that in `A`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So you are saying this would work with C++20 ? Do I need to implement anything additionally or does the compiler know what to do implicitly?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes I thought maybe there is a custom conversion function for this too ... basically converting the type and returning the pointer, no?

Comment: @flxh No, that's not what the cast does.  Essentially what you are trying to do is `int* i_ptr = static_cast<int*>(a_ptr);` which will never work.

Comment: `Foo<Base>` and `Foo<Derived>` are unrelated classes. While `Derived` is derived from `Base`, this is not true for `Foo<Derived>` and `Foo<Base>`. This is actually a well-known problem for `std::vector`s when it contains elements of one type where elements of a compatible type are needed. Finally, element-wise conversion is the only clean way. I.e. in your case: you may cast the contents but you may not cast the smart-pointer.

Comment: the `std::shared_ptr<int>` doesn't point to any dynamically allocated resource. Not sure what you think it would do?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Exactly and because they are unrelated I implemented a custom conversion function. I hoped static_pointer_cast can make use of a custom conversion function just like static_cast ?

Comment: Please note, that doesn't help. In my example, I explicitly mentioned _where elements of a **compatible** type are needed_. ;-) Your conversion produces an RValue which doesn't have an address. Hence, that conversion of values is possible doesn't imply that conversion of the corresponding pointers is supported. A simple example: `double a = 12.3;` `(int)a;` is fully OK but `(int*)&a` is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @flxh `static_cast<int>(a)` works because you are converting an **object** to an `int`, and you defined that conversion. Whereas `static_pointer_cast<int>(pa)` does NOT work because you are trying to convert a `shared_ptr` holding an `A*` **pointer** to a new `shared_ptr` holding an `int*` **pointer**, it is right there in the name - `static POINTER cast` - and there is no conversion defined from `A*` to `int*`, nor can you ever define such a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

> does not compile. Why is that

`std::static_pointer_cast` is for conversions between pointer types. The corresponding bare pointer cast would be:

```
A* a_ptr = &a;
int* i_ptr = static_cast<int*>(a_ptr);
```

That cast is ill-formed, and since `std::static_pointer_cast` that you are attempting will perform this same cast, that is ill-formed as well.

> what do I need to do to make it work?

You can do the same `static_cast` that works in your non-pointer example:

```
int i = static_cast<int>(*pa); //works i = 42
```

However, if you want to have a pointer that shares ownership with `pa` and produces an `int` prvalue on indirection, then I don't think this is achievable with standard smart pointers directly. You could define a custom one. Something along these lines:

```
template<class C, class P>
class converting_ptr {
public:
    converting_ptr(P ptr): ptr(std::move(ptr)) {}

    C operator*() {
        return static_cast<C>(*ptr);
    }

private:
    P ptr;
};

template<class C, class P>
converting_ptr<C, P>
make_converting_ptr(P ptr)
{
    return {std::move(ptr)};
}


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto pi = make_converting_ptr<int>(pa);
    int i = *pi; //works i = 42
}
```

---

P.S. Your `static_cast` is ill-formed because

1. `A a();` is a function declaration.
2. `A::operator int` is private.

Comment: Not any more. C++20 provides a specialization for `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are you sure?  All I can find is they added support to cast from rvalues.  cppreference states even for the new c++20 added overload that `The behavior is undefined unless static_cast<T*>((U*)nullptr) is well formed.`

Comment: This is what I'm looking at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Comment: @SamVarshavchik And on that page it has `The behavior of these functions is undefined unless the corresponding cast from U* to T* is well formed:`  The is no well formed static cast from `A*` to `int*`.

Comment: I double checked that my comment's timestamp was within 5 minutes of the original answer, and I my recollection was that the initial version of this answer was referencing `static_cast`; furthermore my comment was merely the fact that an appropriate specialization of `static_pointer_cast` for `std::shared_ptr` was added in C++20.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `static_pointer_cast` has been around since C++11.  C++20 only added a rvalue reference overload which does the same thing as the lvalue once, but also guaranteed that the passed in pointer is nulled out.

Comment: @eerorika "*if you want to have a pointer that shares ownership with `pa` and produces an `int` prvalue on indirection, then I don't think this is achievable with standard smart pointers directly*" - what about when using `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think you can make that work with a prvalue. It's useful when you have an `int` object whose lifetime is bound to the `A` object. But you don't have such connection between the lifetimes here.